# Review tab indicator disappears

Tags: bug, design, review

A review item often has tabs, like "other answers" and "question". There is a background on the selected tab at first, but clicking on another tab removes that. Here's an example:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

On [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour):

[image]

"Question" I think is selected in the second image since it is a slightly more contrasting color, but it's very hard to tell without the background.

I saw this bug on iOS Chrome. On desktop, the indicator works, but it might be nigh invisible due to a lack of contrast (#D6D9DC vs #FCFBF3 on ELU, a ratio of 1.36 to 1).

---

I believe changing the color on "hover"  (instead of making it the same as the background color) will fix this.

Comment: I really can't understand from the screenshot what the problem is. What exactly disappear? Or is the bug is about black background on sites without dark theme? If so please change title.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Does that help? You can see it on any site by going to a review and clicking on the tabs.

Comment: It works fine here on MSE, and since I just realized only SO has official dark mode and you get it on all sites, it means you're using userscript or browser plugin for that, so 99% the problem you describe is a bug in that userscript or plugin, not in SE. (I see white background, and the selected tab is gray)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars My browser doesn't support userscripts or plugins. It's likely a browser specific issue if you're not seeing it.

Comment: So if you're using browser on PC it's working fine? That would make it mobile/iOS issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars this happens on mobile Android too, as you can see in my answer

Comment: ("EL&U" is a more standard abbr.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to iOS, as I see this on mobile Chrome on Android too:

[image]

When I was on the question tab there was a highlight on that. Once I navigated away to the suggested duplicate the highlighting disappeared. Navigating back to the question also didn't restore the highlighting there.