# The highlight color of the menu selected in the Activity tab is lost when hovering over the menu

Tags: bug, design, activity, highlighting

The background selected highlight color is lost when hovering over a selected menu in the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity).

GIF for reference:

[image: Activity hover issue]

Comment: This might be the same root cause as [Review tab indicator disappears](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385184/323179) (but my phone isn't wide enough to have tabs in the profile).