# The background highlight color for the selected menu in the Activity tab can be improved

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, profile-page, highlighting

The background highlight color for the selected menu in the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) is very low, whereas the background highlight color in the [Settings tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) is more optimal.

Can the same highlight color from the Settings tab be applied to the menus in the Activity tab as well?

**Screenshot from [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity):**

> [image: selected menu highlight color - activity]

**Screenshot from [Settings tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):**

> [image: selected menu highlight color - settings]

Comment: LOL never noticed there is even highlight until you posted it now. And now can't unsee it. :-(

Comment: Also it is weird that [on hover the highlight goes away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01U3Z.png), but then [multiple items are highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esb3p.png) when you hover something else. This seems a little backward. Oh, I see [you already reported that, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385919/165455). +1x2.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't get to say that often, but high contrast dark mode does work better here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxG5c.gif The *main* highlight (currently selected item) stays visible and the secondary one (when hovering) is also different. The contrast between the two could be made starker but they are still visually different (hover only preserves the underline).